# Scipy.stat.gamma.ppf returning inf value

Tags: scipy, gamma-distribution

I  have a list of probabilities containing values between 0 and 1. When I tried to calculate the inverse of that using inverse of gamma function 
by 
scipy.stats.gamma.ppf but it returns inf value for value 1.

can we get some meaningful results instead of inf?

Thank you for the help

```
fit_alpha_z, fit_loc_z, fit_beta_z = st.gamma.fit(data1,floc = 0)

data2  = st.gamma.cdf(data1,a = fit_alpha_z, loc = fit_loc_z,scale = fit_beta_z)

st.gamma.ppf(data2,a = fit_alpha_x, loc = fit_loc_x,scale = fit_beta_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a list of probabilities containing values between 0 and 1. When I tried to calculate the inverse of that using inverse of gamma function by scipy.stats.gamma.ppf but it returns inf value for value 1.

The support of the gamma distribution is unbounded to the right. `stats.gamma(a).cdf(x)` approaches 1.0 as `x` approaches infinity, so `inf` is the most correct result that `ppf` (inverse CDF) can return when passed argument 1.0.